# Do representations of the universal enveloping algebra $\mathrm{U}\mathfrak{su}_2$ retain the Hopf algebra structure?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, noncommutative-algebra

A Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ generates its universal enveloping algebra $\mathrm{U}\mathfrak{g}$, which has the structure of a Hopf algebra.  Modules of $\mathrm{U}\mathfrak{g}$ are exactly the of modules of $\mathfrak{g}$ itself.

In the case $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{su}_2$, the simple modules are labeled uniquely (up to isomorphism) by their dimension, and we label them $V_d$ for $d = 1, 2,$ etc.  Note that $\mathrm{U}\mathfrak{su}_2$ is itself a $\mathfrak{su}_2$ module and decomposes into simple modules as $\bigoplus_{j = 0}^\infty V_{2j+1}$, i.e. only odd-dimensional modules occur.  We can consider truncations of this sum too:
$$\mathrm{U}_J\mathfrak{su}_2 \equiv \mathrm{End}\,V_{2J+1} \simeq V_{2J+1}^\ast \otimes V_{2J+1} \simeq \bigoplus_{j = 0}^{2J} V_{2j+1}$$
In particular, $\dim \mathrm{U}_J\mathfrak{su}_2 = 1 + 3 + \cdots + (4J+1) = (2J+1)^2$, which is $\dim \mathrm{End}\,V_{2J+1}$.  An explicit relationship between the basis adapted to the decomposition of $\mathrm{U}_J \mathfrak{su}_2$ given above and the basis $\{E_{ij}\}$ (with components 1 at $(i,j)$ and 0 elsewhere) on $\mathrm{End}\,V_{2J}$ can be given in terms of the $3jm$ symbols.  The result shows that $\mathrm{U}_J \mathfrak{su}_2$ is isomorphism to $\mathrm{End}\,V_{2J+1}$ as associative algebras.

W. Smoke's paper [Invariant Differential Operators](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1967-127-03/S0002-9947-1967-0210835-1/S0002-9947-1967-0210835-1.pdf) uses the relationship between $\mathrm{U}\mathfrak{su}_2$ and differential operators on the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ group manifold.  (He actually works for a generic Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ but my focus is only on $\mathfrak{su}_2$ for now.)  The filtration of $\mathrm{U}\mathfrak{su}_2$ is the filtration of differential operators by degree, where $\mathrm{U}_J\mathfrak{su}_2$ gives differential operators with degree at most $J$.  At the top of his eighth page (p. 467 in the journal), it is proved that $\mathrm{U}_J \mathfrak{su}_2$ is a subcoalgebra of $\mathrm{U}\mathfrak{su}_2$.

My understanding is that there is no Hopf algebra structure on matrix algebras like $\mathrm{End}\,V_{2J+1} \simeq \mathrm{End}\,\mathbb{C}^{2J+1}$ because they are simple.  There is an algebra structure and a coalgebra structure, but these must not be compatible in the sense of bialgebras.  But in the limit $J \to \infty$ the compatibility seems to be restored, since we know $\mathrm{U}\mathfrak{su}_2$ is a Hopf algebra.  How does this work?

Comment: If two algebras are isomorphic and one of them has an additional Hopf algebra structure then you can transport that structure along the isomorphism; this is called, as you might expect, "transport of structure."

Comment: Excellent.  The construction seems like it should go through to me.  But I'm a physicist and algebra is something I learn on the side meaning I'm not always confident of my hunches.In Hazewinkel et al. "Lie Algebras and Hopf Algebra" I read that the kernel of the counit is a nontrivial ideal in the algebra, but a simple matrix algebra would have no such thing.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. I think your truncation is not a Hopf algebra.

Comment: Oh okay.  What breaks down is the coalgebra structure of $\mathrm{U}_J\mathfrak{su}_2$, or is it the needed compatibility of the algebra and coalgebra structures?

Comment: There are simple Hopf algebras, which I read are those whose algebraic structure is simple.  Why wouldn't the argument above prevent *any* simple Hopf algebras from existing?

Comment: There are no Hopf algebras which are simple as algebras (except the ground field, of course), precisely because of the existence of the counit. On the other hand, there is no finite dimensional Hopf algebra over a field of characteristic zero with a non-zero primitive element.

Comment: In what way is your $U_J\mathfrak{su}_2$ an algebra?

Comment: It's isomorphic to $\mathrm{End}\,V_{2J+1}$, which is an algebra under composition of endomorphisms.

Comment: Is it true in general that the universal enveloping algebra is, as a representation, just a direct sum of exactly one copy of each irrep showing up in the decomposition into irreducibles of the tensor algebra of the adjoint representation? I expect this is already false for $ SU(3) $ but it is just interesting to note that it is true for $ SU(2) $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that $U_J\frak{su}_2$ as you define it, that is $\bigoplus\limits_{j=0}^{2J}V_{2j+1}$, is NOT the space of all differential operators of order at most $J$. For the latter, Formula (2) in the paper suggests that it is the sum $\bigoplus\limits_{j=0}^J S^j(\mathfrak{su}_2)$, so its dimension is equal to the sum $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{J}\frac{(j+1)(j+2)}{2}=\frac{(J+1)(J+2)(J+3)}{6}\ne(2J+1)^2$.

In particular, a natural way to view $U_J\frak{su}_2$ as you define it is as a quotient space of $U\frak{su}_2$, not a subspace, so there is a natural algebra structure but no natural coalgebra structure.